# Getting paragraph in XML DOM (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

I'm trying to create database of new releases from boomkat.com RSS feed. Feed is located here:
[link](http://rss.boomkat.com/boomkat_downloads_just_arrived)

Now, I'm having issues with selection of stuff inside paragraph tags.

One paragraph in RSS feed looks like this:

```
<p>GOAT<br/><a href="http://boomkat.com/downloads/601228-goat-world-music">World Music</a><br/>ROCKET RECORDINGS<br/>INDIE / ROCK / ALTERNATIVE<br/>MP3 Release</p>
```

What I did so far is this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->load("http://feeds.boomkat.com/boomkat_downloads_just_arrived");
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('content');
foreach ($content as $result) {
    echo $result->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

But that gives me whole feed. Writing 'p' in getElementsByTagName doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() method instead of DOMDocument::load() (as load() is strictly for reading XML, not HTML).

The reason why you're getting the whole document, is because you are querying the entire document for a element called "content". There is no such HTML element. Instead you should be using

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

This will grab all the  tags in the HTML document, and then you can loop over that. The primary reason why querying tags with "p" doesn't work, is because you need to load the document as strict HTML, and not use the default XML.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've changed TagName to 'p' and load into loadHTML, but only thing I'm getting now is this: `code` http://feeds.boomkat.com/boomkat_downloads_just_arrived `code`

Comment: DOMDocument::loadHTML() only excepts strings. You're loading a remote file, so you need to use DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(), and not loadHTML().

Comment: I could be of more help, if you provide the proper errors. Do you have error reporting turned on? How do you debug your code?

Comment: To be honest I just started learning PHP/XML couple of days ago and I'm quite new to all this. I'm writing code in Notepad++ and loading script in Google Chrome. How can I actually see what's happening when I execute script?

Comment: Nevermind that, I've turned on all errors, but it doesn't display anything. When I write stuff like "ech" instead of echo it displays error fine, but $content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p'); doesn't display any error and I don't see anything on page.

Comment: can you provide a code sample? it's kind of hard to know what's wrong, if I can't see what you've changed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well I don't understand why you're having problems, but I just tried what I suggested with the URL you provided, and got a proper print out of all the text of each <p> tag.

Here's the code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://boomkat.com/downloads/601228-goat-world-music");
$content = $doc->getElementsByTagName("p");

foreach($content as $element) {
    Util::debug($element->textContent); // helper method similar to PHP's var_dump()
}
```

Here's the results I was able to print to the screen:

```
string(91) "Residual Echoes have come up with a really rather lovely disc of psychedelic folk goodness."

string(8) "MAMMATUS"

string(8) "Mammatus"

string(17) "ROCKET RECORDINGS"

string(45) "MP3 Download // £2.95FLAC Download // £3.95"

string(0) ""

string(19) "SERPENTINA SATELITE"

string(16) "Mecanica Celeste"

string(17) "ROCKET RECORDINGS"

string(45) "MP3 Download // £3.95FLAC Download // £4.95"

string(0) ""

string(12) "SUNCOIL SECT"

string(25) "One Note Obscures Another"

string(17) "ROCKET RECORDINGS"

string(45) "MP3 Download // £6.99FLAC Download // £7.99"

string(0) ""

string(16) "TEETH OF THE SEA"

string(10) "Hypnoticon"

string(17) "ROCKET RECORDINGS"

string(45) "MP3 Download // £2.50FLAC Download // £3.50"

string(52) "Proggy kosmiche rock from London's Teeth Of The Sea."

string(16) "TEETH OF THE SEA"

string(21) "Orphaned By the Ocean"

string(17) "ROCKET RECORDINGS"

string(45) "MP3 Download // £5.99FLAC Download // £6.99"
```

Was this something you were doing in the code?

Comment: That seems to work for that specific link, however I need this link: http://feeds.boomkat.com/boomkat_downloads_just_arrived

Comment: Sorry, my friend, if you can't get it to work as I've demonstrated, then, it is beyond the scope of your question. Try seeking an answer in another question.